# ROOT data analysis framework in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, root

I use the ROOT analysis data framework for work, and it isn't available in the repos anymore (removed from 11.04 due problems compiling due to directory changes in Debian, I think I read).

Anyone tried to compile this is in 11.10, or know if it will be made available later?

Searching for answers is made difficult by its ridiculous name.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to install **root 5.32** from source using [thses instructions](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/installing-root-source) and being careful to include all the [necessary pre-requisites](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/build-prerequisites).

Using Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit is easier, 64 bit root looks for libraries in the wrong places as Ubuntu changed its structure in 11.04, a fix was to manually copy them.

I think it was only copying or linking from here `/usr/local/lib/X11/libX11*` to `/usr/lib32/`

Bit more detail on [How do I install root-cern?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39363/how-do-i-install-root-cern)